# Angular 2 Keyboard Events

Tags: angular

Trying to monitor keyboard events with Angular 2 using TypeScript and [What is Angular2 way of creating global keyboard shortcuts (a.k.a. hotkeys)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35600685/what-is-angular2-way-of-creating-global-keyboard-shortcuts-a-k-a-hotkeys) was helpful but tslint ([codelyzer](https://github.com/mgechev/codelyzer)) objects with the message

> In the "@Component" class decorator you are using the "host"
>   property, this is considered bad practice. Use "@HostBindings",
>   "@HostListeners" property decorator instead.

How do I use the recommended decorators?  I'm not sure how the examples in [Angular 2: Host binding and Host listening](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34719324/angular-2-host-binding-and-host-listening) apply to my use case as I am not binding to any DOM elements.

Here is my demo

```typescript
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
 template: `
    <div>
      <h2>Keyboard Event demo</h2>
      Start typing to see KeyboardEvent values
    </div>
    <hr />
    KeyboardEvent
    <ul>
      <li>altKey: {{altKey}}</li>
      <li>charCode: {{charCode}}</li>
      <li>code: {{code}}</li>
      <li>ctrlKey: {{ctrlKey}}</li>
      <li>keyCode: {{keyCode}}</li>
      <li>keyIdentifier: {{keyIdentifier}}</li>
      <li>metaKey: {{metaKey}}</li>
      <li>shiftKey: {{shiftKey}}</li>
      <li>timeStamp: {{timeStamp}}</li>
      <li>type: {{type}}</li>
      <li>which: {{which}}</li>
    </ul>
      `,
  host: { '(window:keydown)': 'keyboardInput($event)' }
  /*
  In the "@Component" class decorator you are using the "host" property, this is considered bad practice. 
  Use "@HostBindings", "@HostListeners" property decorator instead.
  */

})
export class App {

  /* a few examples */
  keyboardEvent: any;
  altKey: boolean;
  charCode: number;
  code: string;
  ctrlKey: boolean;
  keyCode: number;
  keyIdentifier: string;
  metaKey: boolean;
  shiftKey: boolean;
  timeStamp: number;
  type: string;
  which: number;

  keyboardInput(event: any) {
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();

    this.keyboardEvent = event;
    this.altKey = event.altKey;
    this.charCode = event.charCode;
    this.code = event.code;
    this.ctrlKey = event.ctrlKey;
    this.keyCode = event.keyCode;
    this.keyIdentifier = event.keyIdentifier;
    this.metaKey = event.metaKey;
    this.shiftKey = event.shiftKey;
    this.timeStamp = event.timeStamp;
    this.type = event.type;
    this.which = event.which;
  }

}
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/Aubybjbkp7p8FPxqM0zx

Comment: FYI -- the plunker referenced above isn't working for me in IE 11, but it works nicely in Chrome.  It gets stuck at Loading...

Comment: host: { '(window:keydown)': 'keyboardInput($event)' }

and 

keyboardInput(event: any) {}

is the answer, thanx !!!

Comment: you can try [ngxyz-konami](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngxyz-konami)

Answer (score 35, accepted):

```typescript
import {HostListener} from '@angular/core';

@HostListener('window:keydown', ['$event'])
handleKeyDown(event: KeyboardEvent) {
  // event.key === 'ArrowUp'
}
```

- `@HostBindings('attr.foo') foo = 'bar'` is to bind values from your component instance to the host element like `class`, attributes, properties or styles.

Comment: I have seen it mentioned in comments that using `host: {}` is discouraged and `@HostBinding()`, `@HostListener()` are preferred, but I haven't seen this mentioned from the Angular team.

Comment: How do I do the same for esc key?

Comment: There is no difference. Add `if (event.keyCode == 27) { ... } ` to check if the event is the esc key.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer They did, check it out [here](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/style-guide.html#!#06-03)

Comment: I also recommend you to stay away from `host` as `HostListener` has worked better for key event combinations for me.

Comment: While `@HostListener` works great, it also makes (my) Angular change detection run **for the parent component** on each key press. Using `Observable.fromEvent(window, 'keydown').subscribe(...)` does not. I guess one could create a decorator to run the decorated method outside of Angular's zone, but I've not tried.

Answer (score 1):

Template (.html)

```
<div (keydown)="keyPressed($event)">...</div>
```

Class (.ts)

```
  keyPressed(keyEvent: KeyboardEvent): void {
    if (keyEvent.key === 'ArrowLeft') {
      console.log('LEFT');
    }
    else if (keyEvent.key === 'ArrowRight') {
      console.log('RIGHT');
    }
  }
```

The element where you put the event listener or any of its children must be focused to work. For capturing globally use `<div (window:keydown)...>`.

I think this is a more *Angular way™* alternative. From the [docs](https://angular.io/guide/user-input#get-user-input-from-the-event-object).