# How to handle click events with @Directive?

Tags: angular

Is it possible to attach `click` events to the element on or within a `@Directive` (not `@Component`)?

For example, I have a `@Directive` defined as follows:

```
import { Directive, OnInit, Input, ElementRef, Renderer } from '@angular/core';
declare var $: any; // JQuery

@Directive({
    selector: '[gridStack]'
})
export class GridStackDirective implements OnInit {
    @Input() w: number;
    @Input() animate: boolean;

    constructor(
        private el: ElementRef,
        private renderer: Renderer
    ) {
        renderer.setElementAttribute(el.nativeElement, "class", "grid-stack");
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        let renderer = this.renderer;
        let nativeElement = this.el.nativeElement;
        let animate: string = this.animate ? "yes" : "no";

        renderer.setElementAttribute(nativeElement, "data-gs-width", String(this.w));
        if(animate == "yes") {
            renderer.setElementAttribute(nativeElement, "data-gs-animate", animate);
        }

        let options = {
            cellHeight: 80,
            verticalMargin: 10
        };

        // TODO: listen to an event here instead of just waiting for the time to expire
        setTimeout(function () {
            $('.grid-stack').gridstack(options);
        }, 300);
    }

}
```

In the HTML, where I use that `@Directive` (in `index.html`), note that I do not have any template associated with the `@Directive` itself, can I include a `click` event?:

```
<div gridStack>
    <div><a (click)="clickEvent()">Click Here</a></div>
</div>
```

I know this works if it is a `@Component`, but am looking to try to get it working with a `@Directive` if it is possible.

Answer (score 86, accepted):

You can attach to the click event via `HostListener` decorator in your directive definition.  For example:

```
@Directive({ selector: '[coolBehavior]' })
export class CoolBehaviorDirective {
    @HostListener('click', ['$event']) onClick($event){
        console.info('clicked: ' + $event);
    }
}
```

See the Angular docs [here](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/attribute-directives.html#!#respond-to-user)

And some more info in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34719324/angular-2-host-binding-and-host-listening)

Comment: But this would be for the host (the element the directive is applied to) but not for the children elements... how do you listen to children? (like in his case? or imagine having 2...<div gridStack>
<a (click)="clickEvent1()">Click Here 1</a>
<a (click)="clickEvent2()">Click Here 2</a>
</div>) ?