# Add click event on Component

Tags: angular, typescript

I made a custom button component and I am trying to make a directive that can be applied on the button in order to dynamically add some behavior when the user clicks it :

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[appMyDirective]'
})
export class AppMyDirective {

  // Here, I inject the button instance
  constructor(private button: MyButtonComponent) {
    this.button...what()?
  }

}
```

I could add some code on MyButtonComponent where I handle an array of callbacks but I would prefer to avoid that. How can I dynamically handle the click event on `MyButtonComponent` without modifying its code?

Comment: Do you just need a way to react on click actions within your directive?

Comment: @Nickolaus Yes, do you have a way of doing that?

Comment: `@HostListener` decorator is not enough here?

Comment: should be... I hope the syntax is correct but basically this is how you can listen to any event within a directive or an component

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is pretty simple, just create a function inside your directive:

```
 @HostListener('click', ['$event']) click(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  ... your code
 }
```

see also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34734906/1173391

also usefull:

- offical doc: https://angular.io/api/core/HostListener
- short explanation of HosBinding and HostListener: https://medium.com/@debug_mode/what-are-hostbinding-and-hostlistener-in-angular-985ccf0d4454

Why use `HostListener` and not `addEventListener` on the element?
Angular is smart enough to unsubscribe from the event by itself as the `component`/`directive` gets destroyed. If you use `addEventListener` you will to remove the binding manually otherwise the binding may persist over time.

Answer (score 0):

use ViewContainerRef like this :

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[appMyDirective]'
})
export class MyDirective{

  constructor(
    private viewContainerRef: ViewContainerRef
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    const ele = this.viewContainerRef.element.nativeElement as Element;

    ele.addEventListener('click',e =>{ 
        console.log(e)
    });
  }

}
```

Comment: Works like a charm. I wondering is there is a more "angular-friendly" solution that does not involve getting the native element.

Comment: as @Nickolaus said its much better to use **@HostListener** . i didnt work with angular for a long time and forgot that solution .

Comment: avoid this, to avoid possible memory leaks

Comment: @Nickolaus may i ask why ? i think event listener doesnt destory when directive destories , right ?

Comment: yes... the eventlistener may (must not) still be existing and it can be that the memory which it preserves is not cleared until you leave the page/close the tab...